# Service Worker not recognizing URLs in Fetch event

Tags: service-worker

We are building an progressive web application using service worker.I'm facing an weird issue in `service worker fetch event` that I can see all my URLs in console but few of them are not recognized by Service Worker. Verified that service worker has installed successfully and responding to requests.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
console.log(event.request.url);
}
```

Any idea why this is happening ? 
Note - The URLs which are not getting recognized are actually Ajax calls made using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Explain "not recognizing".

Comment: It means, Not able to apply any URL pattern login in service worker file.Also, Able to see URL in network xhr tab but URL not getting console in above fetch event of sw.

Comment: Could you please provide a standalone demo that exhibits this behavior? You can following the model at https://gist.github.com/jeffposnick/95208ac1b49bf67a096bf6058aab1ed5 and serve it via RawGit, like https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeffposnick/95208ac1b49bf67a096bf6058aab1ed5/raw/e1d775fc8470141726c798bcde3b56913147b421/index.html